# Multiple plots for poisson

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have many different variables:

```
df_poisson <- structure(list(V1 = c(131L, 38L, 19L, 96L, 13L, 34L), 
    V2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), V3 = c(104L, 
    30L, 20L, 72L, 21L, 62L), V4 = c(20L, 12L, 7L, 
    14L, 7L, 18L), V5 = c(38L, 9L, 12L, 31L, 10L, 18L), V6 = c(2L, 
    0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 7L), V7 = c(293L, 87L, 44L, 217L, 
    46L, 156L), V8 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V9 = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V10 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L), V11 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V11 = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), V13 = c(4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L), 
    V14 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V15 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V16 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    V17 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", 
"V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", 
"V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", 
"V17"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Is it possible to plot in line plots these 17 variables and have 17 line poisson plots into the same output?

Comment: It is not clear what kind of plot(s) you are looking for.  Could you please elaborate on the types of plot(s) you want?

Comment: I don't know what a "poisson plot" might be, much less what a plot with 17 of them might look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to fist generate the `Poisson` distribution for variables in `df_poisson`. Something like:

```
#poisson distribution for all columns
df_poisson <- lapply(df_poisson, function(x)ppois(x,1)) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Once `df_poisson` is ready `Poisson`distribution the an option is to use `gather` to change data in long format. And then draw it using `ggplot`.

```
  library(tidyverse)

  df_poisson %>%
    mutate(x = row_number()) %>%
    gather(key, value, -x) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x, value, color = key)) +
    geom_line()
```

[image]